# Python cyclic imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

I think i'm dealing with cyclic imports, but I just can't figure out how to solve the problem.

My project structure

```
sea_battle
    battlefield
        __init__.py
        classes.py
        functions.py
    config
        templates
            __init__.py
            defining_ships.py
            game.py
        __init__.py
        config.py
    gameplay
        __init__.py
        classes.py
    other
        validation.py
    ships
        classes.py
        functions.py
    __init__.py
    run.py
```

battlefield/classes.py

```
from config.config import REVERSED, FIELD_KEYS
from other.validation import Validation


class Battlefield:
    validation = Validation()

    def new_field(self):
        pass


class Cursor:
    validation = Validation()
    Battlefield()
    REVERSED, FIELD_KEYS
```

gameplay/classes.py

```
from battlefield.classes import Battlefield, Cursor
from config.config import SHIPS_EMPTY_SET, SHIPS_ATTR_NAMES, METHODS, PERPENDICULAR, SEARCH_PLAN, FIELD_KEYS
from config.templates.defining_ships import FIELD, EXPLANATIONS
from config.templates.game import GAME
from other.validation import Validation
from random import choice
from ships.classes import Ship
from ships.functions import random_ships_set
import os
import time


class Player:
    validation = Validation()
    SHIPS_EMPTY_SET, SHIPS_ATTR_NAMES


class Opponent:
    SEARCH_PLAN, SHIPS_ATTR_NAMES
    Cursor()
    random_ships_set()
    PERPENDICULAR, METHODS, FIELD_KEYS


class Game:
    validation = Validation()
    Battlefield()
    Player()
    Opponent()
    SHIPS_EMPTY_SET, FIELD, EXPLANATIONS, SHIPS_ATTR_NAMES, GAME
```

config/config.py

```
from battlefield.functions import new_field
from battlefield.classes import Battlefield

FIELD_KEYS = list(new_field().keys())

FIELD_POINTS = list(set(FIELD_KEYS) - {str(num) for num in range(1,11)})
```

ships/classes.py

```
from battlefield.classes import Cursor
from config.config import REVERSED, PERPENDICULAR, FIELD_KEYS
from other.validation import Validation


class Ship:
    Validation()
    REVERSED, PERPENDICULAR
    Cursor()
```

ships/functions.py

```
from .classes import Ship
from battlefield.classes import Cursor
from config.config import SHIPS_EMPTY_SET
from other.validation import Validation
from random import choice, randint


def new_ship():
    Validation()
    Cursor()


def random_ships_set():
    SHIPS_EMPTY_SET
    Validation()
    Ship()
```

I moved the new_field function from battlefield/functions.py to battlefield/classes.py inside a class and then I wanted to change а FIELD_KEYS variable, but got an error on import

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gameplay.classes import Game
  File "sea_battle\gameplay\classes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from battlefield.classes import Battlefield, Cursor
  File "sea_battle\battlefield\classes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from config.config import REVERSED, PERPENDICULAR, FIELD_KEYS
  File "sea_battle\config\config.py", line 2, in <module>
    from battlefield.classes import Battlefield
ImportError: cannot import name 'Battlefield' from 'battlefield.classes' (sea_battle\battlefield\classes.py)
```

Thank you very much in advance.
I expanded the information:

- full project structure
- all imports
- where which imports are applied and in what order

I'm really trying to figure it out, but I can't

- I was trying to move imports to place of use. Remove from file header.
- i tried to move variables FIELD_KEYS and FIELD_POINTS to battlefield/classes.py between Battlefield and Cursor classes

Comment: In Python, files will be loaded once and only once. If a module is only partially loaded, and another module tries to import it again, then you get this error. You should treat of module import dependencies as a directed acyclic graph. Restructure your code to avoid the cycles.

Comment: Are you getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'Battlefield' from partially initialized module 'battlefield.classes' (most likely due to a circular import)`?

Comment: No, i getting:ImportError: cannot import name 'Battlefield' from 'battlefield.classes' @ghchoi

Comment: @flakes  I expanded an information

Answer (score 0):

While interpreting `battlefield.classes`, it imports components from  `config.config`.

```
from config.config import REVERSED, PERPENDICULAR, FIELD_KEYS
```

Thus, while `battlefield.classes` is partially initialized `config.config` is interpreted first. `config.config`, however, also imports components from `battlefield.classes`.

```
from battlefield.classes import Battlefield, new_field
```

So, if you want to import `Battlefield` and `new_field` from partially initialized `battlefield.classes` to `config.config`, you should make sure at least they are initialized.

`battlefield/classes.py`

```
def new_field():
    return {...}

class Battlefield:
    ...

from config.config import REVERSED, PERPENDICULAR, FIELD_KEYS
```

In this way, `Battlefield` and `new_field` can be initialized when `config.config` is interpreted.